# MUI DataGrid - Grouping Array Values

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to use MUI DataGrid to give my user a simple way to report on the number of elements by tag. Each element can have [0,n] tags associated, and when the DataGrid groups on the tag I want to group by each tag rather than the full set of tags.

For example, if there are two users:

```
[
 {
  name: "Bob",
  tags: ["Small", "Fast"]
 },
 {
  name: "Sam",
  tags: ["Small", "Slow"]
 }
]
```

When grouping by tags, I would like there to be three grouped rows ("Small", "Fast", "Slow"), where the "Small" group contains both users, the "Fast" group contains only Bob and the "Slow" group contains only Sam.

I have a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-robinson-ty95bg?file=/src/App.tsx) that demonstrates the basic scenario that I have. It is grouping by all values but I would like to have each group by a **single tag**, and have the rows appear as children of **every** group where that group's tag is associated to the row.

I have implemented valueGetters and valueFormatters, but they still only allow for a single result (and therefore each row can only belong to a single group). The groupingValueGetter leads me to think that there is no way to accomplish my desired functionality currently as the documentation notes:

> The grouping value has to be either a string, a number, null, or undefined

Is it possible to accomplish my desired functionality with MUI DataGrid? I cannot find anything in the documentation that handles custom grouping array fields.